# Inner Join from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

I have 3 tables, as follows:

```
Patron
======
patron_num


Booking_For_Schedule
====================
tname
date
time
booking_num

Booking_By_Patron
=================
booking_num
patron_num
```

I would like to retrieve a result with columns `patron_num`, `date`, `time`, and `tname`, like so:

```
patron_num     date      time     tname
     1      2013-11-03  20:00    TestName
```

...etc

The purpose of this homework question is to teach us INNER JOINS, but I am having some difficulty. Could some kind SO user push me in the right direction?

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT `patron_num`,`date`,`time`,`tname`
FROM `booking_for_schedule` `F`
INNER JOIN `booking_by_patron` `B` on `F`.`booking_num` = `B`.`booking_num`
INNER JOIN `patron` `P` on `B`.`patron_num`=`P`.`patron_num`
```

which returns the error: `#1052 - Column 'patron_num' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: My push will be to learn to read error messages.  The one you got was quite explicit.  This is not always the case.

Comment: You're very close with what you have as others have indicated below.  As you think about why it's important to define which table you pull from ask yourself is it possible to have a patron_num without a Patron? or perhaps a booking_num without a booking_by_patron?  This will becomes important to understand as you learn about outer joins (left, right, full) which I believe are well explained [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `P`.`patron_num`,`date`,`time`,`tname`
FROM `booking_for_schedule` `F`
INNER JOIN `booking_by_patron` `B` on `F`.`booking_num` = `B`.`booking_num`
INNER JOIN `patron` `P` on `B`.`patron_num`=`P`.`patron_num`
```

Will help with the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! I think my problem was that I figured that patron_num shouldn't be ambiguous since my inner join is on the two patron_num's being equal.

Answer (score 1):

Since `patron_num` is in multiple tables you need to specify which one you want to use.  You can do this by adding the table alias before it like you are in your joins.  Example:

```
SELECT `B`.`patron_num`,`date`,`time`,`tname`
FROM `booking_for_schedule` `F`
INNER JOIN `booking_by_patron` `B` on `F`.`booking_num` = `B`.`booking_num`
INNER JOIN `patron` `P` on `B`.`patron_num`=`P`.`patron_num`
```